# cannot connect to VM

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

I made a test class in my android project to check if my database works. But when I want to debug this class it gives me an error: "Cannot connect to VM", in details it says also "Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking". When I try debugging a test class in another project it works and debugging my other classes in the android project also works. Can the problem be that I try to run a normal test on an android project?

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You probably figured this out already, but for others who get stuck in this situation, here is my answer.
I've had this problem a couple of times myself now, and I finally found out that it's related to

> including a "main" method in your android class files:
>    **Don't do it!**
>
> Run Configuration in Eclipse:
>    **Delete the automatically created application configurations**

The following link provides a very good explanation about the problem, the solution, and the reasons:
http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/16/solved-internal-error-classfileparser-cpp3161/

Comment: ecliplse run/run configurations...  click the x to delete.  I got a main method in my new class file automatically while adding a service class to the project and selecting the service super class.  usually when I do this it adds the necessary stubs but this time yes it did add the main method.

Answer (score 3):

It caused by having a "main" method.
Delete/rename the method and then go to the properties of the project.
Click "Run/Debug Settings" and delete the class (it may make eclipse to run the class after being compiled).

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the Test Launcher being used.

```
Run->Debug Configurations->JUnit->*JUnit Test Class*
```

Choose **Select Other** in the bottom left of the settings dialog, next to the menu list.

[image]

Comment: click the red x to delete this configuration