# Cannot run junit on project

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to run junit tests in a project (in eclipse - Windows), but it is not working

1. If I select "Run As / Junit Test" nothing happens.
2. If I try to debug the project in Junit I got the following message:

*Cannot connect to VMSocket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking*

3. If I create a new project and try to run junit, it works!
4. The same project runs in another 2 computers with Ubuntu
5. If go to "Debugg Configurations" e remove the configuration associated with the test class i'm trying to run sometimes it works, but only for 1 time.
6. Tested in Netbeans and it worked, but i still to make it work in Eclipse.

What I already tried to do:
 - I already tried turning firewall off with no success.
 - I have not any main method in this project.
 - I already cleaned, cloned and import this again.
 - I already removed junit debugging configurations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot connect to VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374628/cannot-connect-to-vm)

Comment: You may have confused Eclipse.  Consider recreating the workspace.

Comment: Done that, didnt work.

Comment: Unique solution i found to this problem was reinstalling my SO.